# how to get channel name at runtime in springxd

Tags: redis, spring-xd

I have a stream defined as stream create --name foo --definition samplesource | sampleprocessor | samplesink --deploy. I'm using Redis as MessageBus.

If sampleprocessor or samplesink is failed, then xd will push failed messages to Redis into ERRORS:foo.n queue. I'm writing code to bring the messages from errors queue to foo.n.

Challenge here is I don't want to hardcode the stream name in my code as this piece is handled across all my xd modules.

Can we get the channel name on the fly ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing code...

Where is that code going to run?

If it's within a module in the stream, module metadata is available via the application context environment properties:

```
    ${xd.group.name}
    ${xd.module.label}
    ${xd.module.type}
    ${xd.module.sequence}
```

Comment: We are build a separate xd stream (errorsrc | errsink) which reads the err msgs from RedisBus and pushes them to destination queue. So I need all the queues from all the streams defined in that XD env.